# Synchronous Terminal Input with nodejs

Tags: node.js

Is there any way or package to get synchronous input from the terminal all the one I could find like `readline-sync` and `prompt-sync` are no longer maintain and other like `inquirer`, `prompt` and `prompts` are all asynchronous (needing to be put in a `async` block and use `await`)